# Why does Google Cloud Tools Plugin for Eclipse say "No Projects Found"?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I'm migrating from Java7 to Java8 and from the old GAE plugin to the new Cloud Tools plugin.

I think I've got it mostly set up correctly - but when I try and run the app I get a 403.  And when I look at the Google Cloud Platform section of the Properties the only option is "App Engine Deployment" and when I open that it tells me "No Projects Found".

I'm signed in to Google in Eclipse.  When I look at https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager it shows me two projects (one of which is the correct one).

The console shows the following:

```
2017-12-31 18:40:37.513:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2741ms
2017-12-31 18:40:38.073:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.18.v20170406
2017-12-31 18:40:41.859:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed time=3321ms
2017-12-31 18:40:42.498:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started c.g.a.t.d.j.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@25bcd0c7{/,file:///C:/Users/andre_000/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/Postr/,AVAILABLE}{C:\Users\andre_000\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\Postr}
2017-12-31 18:40:42.520:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started NetworkTrafficSelectChannelConnector@5db4c359{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{localhost:8080}
2017-12-31 18:40:42.522:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @7751ms
Dec 31, 2017 6:40:42 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8080/
Dec 31, 2017 6:40:42 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
Dec 31, 2017 6:40:42 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your console output is from the *development app server*, a local emulator that runs on your development machine (`http://localhost:8080`). You can use this emulator for debugging your app. Once you're happy with your app, you then *deploy* it to App Engine which then makes your app available through `.appspot.com`.

Comment: My point is that it *doesn't* appear on localhost. Instead I get the 403.

Comment: Just to clarify, the exact same app engine project when run locally does not work (with 403) with <runtime>java8</runtime> in the appengine-web.xml but does work without it?